# Get back Documents folder?

Tags: filesystem

I deleted my documents and downloads folder. How can I get them back. I don't want them to be like any other folder, I would like it to be like how it used to be where it shows on the side of the filesystem. Any idea on how i can get it back like that.

Comment: What do you mean “at the side of the filesystem”? Do you mean the side bar of the file manager (Nautilus by default)? Please post a screenshot, if unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new Documents folder

1. Open home folder
2. Right click and create new folder, name it Documents
3. Change icon by right click on the Documents folder and select properties. Click on the folder icon, this will bring up a select custom icon window.
   Browse to File System > usr > share > icons > Humanity > places > 48 & select the 1st folder_documents.svg. This should restore the icon to your Downloads folder
4. Then execute `gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in terminal (Press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal) or browse to file. You'll see this line - `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/` edit it to `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"`

Similarly for restoring Downloads folder repeat above steps but replace Documents with Downloads in each Step.